# How to resize and compress image with relatively good quality in Android?

Tags: android, image, image-processing, kotlin

So I want to limit the file size that uploaded to server, I want the image to be around 250kb with relatively good quality that uploaded to server.  at the moment, I just can decrease the file size but with low quality image result.

For example, I have original jpeg image dimension 1000x1000, and it's size is 150kb. i try the reduce the width and height (in order to reduce the file size) to be 450 x 450, the file size then become 137kb, the file size just decrease little bit, but the quality is very low. I expect the quality is relatively close if just decrease from 150kb to 137kb.

I don't know how to decrease the overall file size, so I assume that I can decrease the file size by reducing the width and height to be 450x450.

here is the code I use:

after selecting image from gallery, the Uri will be transformed to be bitmap:

```
val originalSizeEventPosterBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(mActivity.contentResolver, eventPosterUri)
```

and then, I resize the bitmap to be 450x450

```
val resizedEventPosterBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(originalSizeEventPosterBitmap,450,450,true)
```

I store the image in Firebase storage, and it requires the file transfered in ByteArray data type (it also can be transfered in Uri data type). so then I convert the bitmap from `resizedEventPosterBitmap` to be ByteArray first before uploading to server using the function below:

```
fun getBytesArrayFromBimap(image: Bitmap) : ByteArray {
        val stream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream)
        val bytesArrayData = stream.toByteArray()
        image.recycle()
        return bytesArrayData
    }
```

the result of that function then send to server.

can You share your code or library to reduce the image size when you want to upload image to server ?

because the code I use above still make the image size quite big with low quality image

Comment: following link may help you https://github.com/hkk595/Resizer and 
https://github.com/zetbaitsu/Compressor

Comment: Thank you very much, using those libraries will give a very good result in compressing and resizing image